# Flutter future builder is not scrolling

Tags: flutter

I have a Future builder widget which gets data from firestore
It is getting the data but not scrolling

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: getpro(docpro),
                  builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return ListView(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              children: [
                                ListTile(
                                  title: Text(
                                    snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["Title"],
                                    style
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `Column` with `SinglechildScrollView`, for `ListView.builder` you need to set:

```dart
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    shrinkWrap: true,
```